# Black border on single table cell css

Tags: html, css

Just cannot imagine how to do a single table cell border black. Just like it is in excel - whole table TD borders are, for example, white, and selected cell has black border.
The obvious solution is to change borders of the nearest cells as well, but the table is dynamically generated ant it takes too much effort to calculate current cell's neighbours. Although, the current cell is known from the "click" event, so it would be great to achieve that styling it.
Tried to put the div inside but cannot align it without specifying cell and div sizes exactly in pixels, that is not portable.
Please help!

Sorry, thought it's obvious without code. Actually, I don't have a code that's working, but currently I'm trying that (wrote just a quick sample, sorry):
https://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/10/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="selected">
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>    <tr>
        <td>
                        <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

And css (dunno why, this site asks me to paste the code here)

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 1em;
}
td
{
    font-size: 1rem;
    empty-cells: show;
    border: 1px solid rgba(230,222,255,1);
    padding: 0;
}
td#selected
{
    font-size: 1rem;
    empty-cells: show;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    padding: 0;
}

tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #efedee;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    overflow: visible;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f6f4f5;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    overflow: visible;
}
input[type=text]
{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border: 0px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 1rem;
}
```

Hope it will help to understand the problem

This is how I want it to llok like
[image: This is how I want it to llok like]
This is how it really looks like now
[image: This is how it really looks now]

Solution provided by [Shaggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768433/shaggy) : https://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/14/
Thank you!

Comment: Pleas epaste some code that you hvae tried. It will help us to understand it properly.

Comment: I think I know what you're looking for but I'm making the assumption that you're collapsing the borders of your table. Without a sample of your code, though, to confirm that, I can't provide an answer.

Comment: Here's the code. It does not matter, wheter I have collapsed or separate borders. In both cases I cannot achieve what I want.
I suppose, it is possible to use some kind of absolute positioning for the inner div ti make it overflow current cell for the specified amount of pixels, but don't really understand how to do that /

Comment: The Fiddle you provided is working as you described; the 4 borders of the middle cell are black. What's the problem?

Comment: Well, I've updated fiddle increasing borders width to 5px, so you could see what's wrong. The whole border should be black, but there's neighbours borders around
https://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/9/

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh55e/71/

Comment: Thank you, it's almost what I need, but, as I mentioned before, my table is dynamically generated rendering data from the java servlet, and my script actually don't know what size these cells should have. Can it be done for a table cells with unknown/arbitrary sizes? I tried to put one div in another but without success because, as I understand, I have to provide absolute width/height for "position: absolute" div (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the adjacent cell borders is still going to cause you a problem as, on the cell above, for example, you'll have the left and right borders cutting in to the bottom border slightly as illustrated in this snippet:

```css
div{
    border:10px solid;
    border-color:#000 #f00 #090 #009;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Instead, what you're going to need to do is collapse the borders of your table and then, for the active cells, use an absolutely positioned pseudo element to create the highlighted border, setting all 4 positioning values to the negative pixel value of the size of your border.

Here's a quick example using `:hover` to illustrate the principle:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    border:5px solid #ccc;
    background:#eee;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
td:hover::before{
    border:5px solid #000;
    bottom:-5px;
    content:"";
    left:-5px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    top:-5px;
    z-index:1;
}
div{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
div,input{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As an alternative, rather than giving each individual cell an initial border, you could use `border-spacing` instead, like so:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
table{
    background:#ccc;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
td{
    background:#eee;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
td:hover::before{
    border:5px solid #000;
    bottom:-5px;
    content:"";
    left:-5px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    top:-5px;
}
div{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
div,input{width:100%;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
            <td><div><input></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow!
I swear I tried absolute positioning inside relative with negative side offsets! And it was not working!
Thank you so much! It's a kind of magic!!! Be honest, you've updated browsers rendering engine somehow? )
Well, thank you! it's exactly what I need. The little problem is, that internal div is still "under" adjacent cells (in rendering order, from top to bottom):
https://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/12/
So, I gave a zIndex to it, but just wonder, why it's not so in your example.
https://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/13/
Thank you again! It works!

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is a fresh pair of eyes. As to your question, just put it down to quirks of tables! ;) I've updated my Snippets above to use `z-index` instead of `pointer-events` to give you better cross-browser compatibility. If this post has answered your question to your satisfaction, you might consider accepting it :)

Comment: I've reproduced my problem. In case I made all divs like selected one, the whole page is messed up: https://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/15/
Could you please explain me why?
As I understand, neighbour cells create a size constraints for this selected one?

Comment: You're absolutely positioning the `div` which is taking it out of the normal flow of the page with one of the side-effects being that its parent `td` won't expand to fit it's dimensions. You either need to define the dimensions of the `td`, which you've already said is not an option, or use a pseudo element, as I've done above.

Comment: -̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶o̶o̶b̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶,̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶c̶c̶e̶p̶t̶?̶-
Found it! 10x! ))

Comment: Yes, I understand that pretty well, just dodn't knew that ::before can insert something other than just a pure content (something like .innerHTML+=)) Shame on me and thank you! )

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get current cell and then change its class to other class that defines visible borders

jquery :

```
$("#cell").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('not-selected selected');
});
```

css :

```
.not-selected{
   border: 0px;
}
.selected{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: It will either left border from neighbour cells (with border-collapse: separate) or just jam border (with collapse)

Comment: Sorry, that's probably due to my poor english.
My question was not how to change class, it's obvious. The question is, how to draw single cell border without changing neighbour cells.